# QueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection() not returning or throwing an exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, websphere, mq

When my MQ server becomes unavailable, the call to QueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection() hangs and eventually (1-2 minutes later) "javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout" is thrown.

I cannot find a JavaEE call to set a timeout for the function.

Is there a way to get this function to fail faster or throw an exception on WebSphere when the MQ server cannot be reached?

The QCF is accessed by dependency injection.

```
@Resource(name = "jndi-name-for-QCF")
private QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory;

   …

// this line is timing out.
QueueConnection connection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
```

Comment: When the MQ server is down, shouldn't an `IOException` be thrown? Please clarify if I'm missing something here.

Comment: I'd expect something like that and it's what I want to happen, but this isn't happening for me. The createQueueConnection() call simply hangs and eventually the EJB container times out the transaction. createQueueConnection() may be stuck in a loop attempting to reconnect to the server. I don't know. I've tried setting the advanced QCF property reconnect=DISABLED, but with the same behavior.

Comment: One additional clarification: Does the transaction timeout occur when the application connects _while_ the QMGR is quiescing? What happens when you try _after_ the QMGR is completely shut down?

Comment: Could you please clarify your definition of 'down'? You may actually be suffering from a timeout delay in the TCP stack, which might be taking 1/2 minutes to return a timeout to the JVM.

Comment: Down is when the MQ server is rebooted for upgrades or maintenance, usually off hours. WebSphere is on a different server and isn't cycled at the same time. After the MQ server is back up, the behavior persists until restarting the application cluster. A better solution should be setting the QCF property "client reconnect options" to RECONNECT. (will get to it) I still need to deal with the scenario when MQ is simply down. I haven't been able to test if I need a live MQ connection to go dead before seeing this problem, i.e., what happens when MQ is down before WebSphere starts?

Answer (score 1):

I think typically this would be handled administratively with config rather than programmatically in your app code.   E.g. see [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0903_halstead/0903_halstead.html) for some examples.

Not sure there's much you can do with configuring the WebSphere connection pooling settings either.  This seems to point to configuring the MQ provider itself (e.g. the channels).

Comment: I don't see the answer to my more immediate problem at the link, but there's lots of valuable information about dealing with MQ server disconnects that I haven't started to address yet. Thank you.